# How can I select query in laravel view in 2 arrays

Tags: laravel

I make select by id and path the variable to `NewsDetailsResource`:

```
$NewsData = News::query()->where('id', $id)->first();
$this->body['NewsData']=NewsDetailsResource::make($NewsData);
```

and `NewsDetailsResource` source code:

```
return [
    'id' => $this->id, 
    'slug' => $this->slug, 
    'title' => $this->title,   
     'auther' => $this->auther, 
    'description' => $this->description,
    'logo' => config('app.url').$this->logo, 
    'date' => date('d-m-Y', strtotime($this->created_at))      
];
```

Now I want to display result in two arrays;
first array

```
 'id' => $this->id, 
            'slug' => $this->slug, 
            'title' => $this->title,   
            'auther' => $this->auther, 
            'date' => date('d-m-Y', strtotime($this->created_at))
```

Second array

```
   'description' => $this->description,
            'logo' => config('app.url').$this->logo,
```

The result in JSON must be

```
 const HeroSectionData = [
    {
    
      basicData: [
        {
            "title": "ASdasda sad a SAd",
            "slug": "sdasdasd",
            "Auther": "sdasdasd",
            "date": "01-08-2023"
        }
      ],
      descriptionData: [
        {
            description: "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.",
            logo: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzQid.png?s=32&g=1",
         }
      ],
    
    }
  ];
```

Comment: Just modify the `NewsDetailsResource`. `return [ 'basicData' => ['title' => ..., ], 'descriptionData' => ['description' => ..., 'logo' => ...] ];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your `NewsDetailsResource` source code like below:

```
return [
    'basicData' => [
       'id' => $this->id, 
       'slug' => $this->slug, 
       'title' => $this->title,   
       'auther' => $this->auther, 
       'date' => date('d-m-Y', strtotime($this->created_at))      
    ],
    'descriptionData' => [
        'description' => $this->description,
        'logo' => config('app.url').$this->logo, 
    ]
];
```